# Overlay a JPanel on a JPanel that has a JFXPanel with a video playing

Tags: java, swing, awt, frontend

I am trying to overlay a JPanel on a JPanel that contains a JFXPanel with a video on loop.

I have a class that extends JPanel and adds a JFXPanel with the video. What I am trying to do is to reuse this class (that I use for playing other videos) putting it as a background of the main menu (the other JPanel).

I have achieved to put the JPanel with the video on top with the other JPanel on background, but not otherwise.

```
JPanel panelContingut = (JPanel) framePrincipal.getContentPane();
panelContingut.removeAll();
JPanel fons = new MMReproductor("FileName");
fons.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
panelContingut.add(fons);
panelContingut.add(pLayoutMenú.layout());  //pLayoutMenú.layout() is the J
refrescar(panelContingut);  //This just packs, revalidates and repaints.
```

Then on MMReproductor...

```
public class MMReproductor extends JPanel{
    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    public MMReproductor(String nom){
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Media m = new Media(getClass().getResource(nom).toString());
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
        MediaView mv = new MediaView(mp);

        ...

        final DoubleProperty width = mv.fitWidthProperty();
        final DoubleProperty height = mv.fitHeightProperty();
        width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
        height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));
        mv.setPreserveRatio(false);

        ...

        mp.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mp.seek(Duration.seconds(0));
            }
        });

        ...

        Group grup = new Group(mv);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grup);
        jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        add(jfxPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mp.play();
    }
}
```

I have tried several things but found no solution, I just get the second JPanel with the video on top. Also, when I hover any button on the first JPanel (on the visible part), it (the button) becomes fully visible (as it was only half visible for the setBounds of the second JPanel), but it gets covered again for the second JPanel with the video (maybe because some kind of repaint of MediaView when next frame has to be shown).

Comment: It's possible that the JavaFX video panel doesn't not support Z-Ordering, or at least not with in a Swing context

Comment: @MadProgrammer any recommendations then? I was about to try JMF but before getting to it I read it was too old and that JavaFX was better.

Comment: I don't know if `Media` would have the same issue in a pure JavaFX application, Swing and JavaFX are using different painting methods, so there inoperability may be limited (and I don't know how you'd add a Swing component to a JavaFX panel either).  Almost all the pre-existing video solutions require direct access to the native peer to work, which means that they have no concept of the z-ordering Swing uses - as they are painted directly to the native peer and not through Swing's painting process - there may not be a solution for your problem

Comment: I should point at this is all speculation on my part, I've never tried mixing Swing and JavaFX

Comment: It makes sense, seems I'll have to get rid of JavaFX. Thank-you for helping!